# Cannot send SMTP Email from Outlook VSTO Addin

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins, system.net.mail

I have a `SendEmail` method developed with `System.Net.Mail` that works fine.   Calling it from my `VSTO Outlook Addin`, I get an error: A call to SSPI failed.   The inner error contains "Function not supported".

I tried to send the same email from a regular c# environment (that worked), and from my Outlook VSTO add-in that did not.

Is there a reason why the smtp email cannot be sent from the Addin?

**Solution** (thanks to Eugene), I added

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

to the SendEmail method and now the Emails are sent.

Comment: Does it work correctly if you run the same code from a Windows forms application on the same machine?

Comment: I used Linqpad.   And the email was sent.

Comment: Could you be more specific and post the code which doesn't work?

Comment: I wonder why you mixed the Outlook object model and .net `MailMessage` in the same place?

Comment: The idea was to have the user compose an email and add attachments, and use the corporate smpt email application to send the emails.    The sender in this case is not the account that uses outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the nature of the exception, it seems like you're more likely to have an email server problem than anything else.

Also it makes sense to check what TLS version is used in the code. SSPI stands for `Security Support Provider Interface`, so it makes sense try to find the difference between two .net applications. TLS is a starting point, see [How to enable TLS 1.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2) for more information.

You may consider your Outlook VSTO add-in as a regular .net application. There are minor differences like availability of configurations files and etc. If you need to put something into a config file you need to create a config for the host application which is Outlook in your case. Keep that in mind when developing VSTO add-ins.

Comment: Could you give me an example of what it would be that I need to configure?

Comment: Try to run the `SendEmail2` method from a windows forms application.

Comment: that works.   It's used a lot in a Windows forms application.

Comment: Is there any difference in security settings between the two .net apps?

Comment: I'm referencing the windows app from the addin and use the same method in both cases.  Is that an answer to your question?  So the TLS settings are the same.

Comment: You were right:  I added "ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12" and now it works;